# Cygwin - How can I keep original file name when outputting results of a command on a file (cut command)?

Tags: cygwin

I'm using a cut command to split up a file.  I need the output of the file to keep the original file name.  I will not know the name of the file, just what folder it is located in.  I need to ultimately add a suffix and prefix to original file after the cut, which I've got figured out.  My issue is that I do not know how to keep the original file name after I output the cut.

cut -d, -f1,2,3 for file in * $file > originalfilename.txt

There should only be 1 file in the "dropbox" folder at one time.  So if I can store the variable of that file name somewhere and use later that works for me.

Also if there is a way to just modify the file using cut, rather than needing to output it somewhere this would satisfy my needs too, because I would obviously still have original file name then.

I just started using Cygwin a few days ago so I apologize if there is really an obvious answer to this!  I have googled everything and couldn't find what I needed.

Comment: You basically look inside somedir/file for an `originalfilename` and then you want to save this file name into a variable or another file, right? Mind giving us an excerpt of these files and the naming convention of these files? I feel like you could do this very easily.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, unix cut does not offer an in-place option.  However you can look at alternate options [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/can-i-make-cut-change-a-file-in-place)

Comment: Thank you my issue is I won't know file name!  I think I can work around this though.  There are only 12 options the name can be so I can just look for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You define a variable to store the name of the file and use that variable in the commands:
`orig_file='originalfilename.txt'<br>
cut -d, -f1,2,3 for file in * $file > $orig_file <br>
echo "The name of the original file is $orig_file"`